# Dlib Face Landmark Detection Linker Error

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, linker, dlib

I've recently installed OpenCV 3.0 from source. I then installed Dlib through Homebrew on macOS Sierra 10.12 since I want to learn more about computer vision.

I was trying to compile [the facial landmark detection](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html)  program found on Dlib's website and I am getting the following linker error and I have been unsuccessful in finding the right compiler flags to fix this. I'm also not sure if I actually have the required software installed.

The linker error I'm getting is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_DGifCloseFile", referenced from:
void dlib::load_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in face_landmark_detection-7a9d91.o
"_DGifOpenFileName", referenced from:
  void dlib::load_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in face_landmark_detection-7a9d91.o
"_DGifSlurp", referenced from:
  void dlib::load_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in face_landmark_detection-7a9d91.o
"_cblas_dgemm", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_gemm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, double, double const*, int, double const*, int, double, double*, int) in face_landmark_detection-7a9d91.o
"_cblas_saxpy", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_axpy(int, float, float const*, int, float*, int) in face_landmark_detection-7a9d91.o
"_cblas_sscal", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_scal(int, float, float*) in face_landmark_detection-7a9d91.o
"_dgesvd_", referenced from:
  dlib::lapack::binding::gesvd(char, char, int, int, double*, int, double*, double*, int, double*, int, double*, int) in face_landmark_detection-7a9d91.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

(I installed with --HEAD because `brew install opencv3` would not work for me)
Homebrew installed OpenCV: `brew tap homebrew/science; brew install --HEAD opencv3`
Homebrew installed Dlib: `brew install dlib`

Compile flags:
`g++ -std=c++11 face_landmark_detection.cpp 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv dlib-1'`

Output of pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv dlib-1:

> -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-de35c59_4/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-de35c59_4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.1_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.25/include/libpng16 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-de35c59_4/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.1_2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.25/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -ldlib -lpng16

Can anyone please tell me which files need to be linked?

Comment: how about using cmake?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Oops! I forgot to add the OS. I added it in the first sentence. I am on OS X El Capitan. I wanted to install them with Homebrew so that there would be less work for me if any updates ever happen to either library. I totally will install both with cmake if I don't figure this out.